# iPhone app: scale of testing unit in unit test

Tags: iphone, unit-testing

When I was looking into unit testing for iPhone projects, I found that it is hard to decide the scale of unit in unit testing, so if I have three methods A, B and C, I can test each of them, but sometimes you need to call A before B in order to make B making sense, for example, if I have addImageWithName: and removeImageWithName:, then I need to first add an image, in order to test if removeImageWithName: really works.

So it is the decision between black box single method test or functional test(functional means a function of the application which may involve more than one method), if the time is tight then I cannot go with both of them, so what is the pros and cons of these two approaches?

What I can think of:

=== single method test ===
pros:
- easy to write test case, as you only need to deal with input/output of individual methods
cons:
- methods need to highly decoupled, so one method does not rely on another
- sometimes impossible for example the undo method has to rely on a 'do' method.

=== functional test ===
pros:
- higher level than per method test, as this targets at functions of the app

cons:
- not easy to write test case, if the function is complicated
- may not cover all the cases for each individual method involved in a particular function

So what should be the correct decision?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single method test it the best way to write unit test in xcode. Anyway if your function depends on another function to complete the you can use asynchronous unit test, Use GHUnit test framework for testing the async methods.
BTW: what you are using, OCUnit or GHUnit for testing?
hope this help

Comment: have you tried it using using GHUnit async test.

Comment: No I haven't. I'll have a look. Thanks!